# Gcloud command line structure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am having trouble understanding why some gcloud command parameters are key value pairs,

eg. `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project=ProjectID`

and other parameters are space separated,

eg. `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --version VersionID.`

Is there some sort of organizational scheme to which parameters are equal separated vs. space separated?

I've put a full command below for reference

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml --version VersionID --project=ProjectID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equal sign after a flag is optional, but after a property you have to use a space.

[Difference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/properties#properties_and_flags) between [properties](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/#properties) and [flags](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/)